# Starting TDD on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tdd

I'm currently learning TDD and have finished reading a book. Now that I'm about to start an ASP.NET MVC project, it seems its hard to do the "no code without failing test rule", at least in terms of starting.

Should I add the needed folders at the start like Controllers, and any other infrastructure-related files? Just add them? It seems its hard to start, does everything need to fail a test first? And how do I do it for the front-end? It seems its quite complicated when its not the business logic being tested. Could you guys point me to some resources for employing TDD for Views/Front-end?

Comment: IMHO TDD is more of a "religion" than a best practice. There are those that believe, and those that don't. I tried it and it worked well on a small project, but [if there is no planned architecture it can be really difficult to do on a larger project](https://dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-test-driven). In short, tests are good. But writing them first is more of a pie in the sky than a necessity - for large projects it is usually better to flesh out the design first, then add tests starting with the most difficult things to test manually, as time allows.

Comment: [Here is another great article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week01oct15/test-driven-development-the-larger-issues/) outlining the pitfalls of TDD.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a failing test, the test must be run. In order to be able to run the test, the unit test project must be able to compile. Therefore you should add the Controllers folder and at least a controller and an action. This is, IMHO, the bare minimum.

Write the first action with a single throw new NotImplementedException(); line of code.

Then write a test that exercises the method and asserts that the result is not null or of a given type (for example ViewResult type).

Now run the test and see it fails. The TDD supporters will cheer in the arena.

Next you can replace the single line of code (the not implemented exception) with a bit of actual code and repeat.